# How to avoid duplicate content? redirect 301/404?

Tags: php, redirect, seo

lets say i have this link: 
http://www.domain.com/content/view/1/seo-url

now, lets say a user misspeled the link - 
http://www.domain.com/content/view/1/seo-urll

now, i dont want him to get a 404 page, I want to redirect him to the right page with the right seo url, BUT - i dont want to create duplicate content (on google's side).

What to do?

```
header("....");
header("location: righturl");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`303 See Other`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303), I'd say. Either that or a [canonical URL](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) in a `<meta />` tag.

Actually I'm in doubt since 302 is sometimes referred to as `302 Found [Elsewhere]`:

> It is an example of industry practice
>   contradicting the standard HTTP/1.0
>   specification (RFC 1945), which
>   required the client to perform a
>   temporary redirect (the original
>   describing phrase was "Moved
>   Temporarily"), but popular browsers
>   implemented it as a 303 See
>   Other, i.e. changing
>   the request type to GET regardless of
>   what it had been originally.
>   Therefore, HTTP/1.1 added status codes
>   303 and 307 to disambiguate between
>   the two behaviours.

([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302))

Comment: The 303 redirection is primarily for responses on POST request. Additionally, a 303 response is not cacheable.

Answer (score 2):

You must redirect the user with a 301 (never use 302!) header.
You will not get dublicate content problems, and possible linklove goes to the correct url.

Comment: Why never a 301? I mean, 'moved permanently' may not be the perfect description of this problem, but at least it passes pagerank to the right url. 302 doesn't, so that would still divide pagerank over the two pages

Comment: shoot me now. I meant it the other way around! I'll fix it quickly :)(